# Can Azure AD B2C profile content be customized?

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm pretty sure the answer is no, but I'll ask anyway.

According to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization/, B2C administrators wishing to customize their UI need to

> create well-formed HTML5 content with a `<div id="api"></div>` element (needs to be an empty element) located somewhere in the `<body>`. This element marks where the Azure AD B2C content is inserted.

It looks like B2C then inserts the information you configure regarding the profile or other policy into that tag.

If you have some tedious HTML - like for example, a list of all universities in the world - you have to enter this information by hand and cannot sort it.

If you're not familiar with the profile, then the question doesn't make sense. When defining the profile, you can create custom fields. MS controls the UI for these custom fields. In their profile UI customization, you can define the way a field is drawn in HTML as Text, DropDown, CheckBox, or Radio Button. For the last three, you have an extremely simplistic UI for entering your data that populates the options.

So, if you have a field for University (which I do) and you have 4,000 entries for Option (which I do), you have to manually enter each option in their UI in the order you wish it to appear. At a minimum, it would be nice to just import this data into the store in which they are keeping this data. At a maximum, it would be really nice you just draw all this HTML myself in my own CSHTML.

Is it/Will it be possible to render those fields from my own HTML/CSHTML?

Is it/Will it be possible to enter the needed data in an easier to use manner (import, direct database manipulation, etc.)?

Comment: What do you mean with the list of universities, is that data in the B2C Profile (and inserted into the DIV) or is this content you wish to show on the same page?

Comment: @ErikOppedijk : I edited the question for you.

Comment: Now it's clear, it is a lot of editing in the profile UI customization screen! I think the answer is No at this moment

Comment: @ErikOppedijk I'm pretty sure that is the answer for now as well. Since the B2C team monitors SO, I was hoping they would weigh in.

Comment: Out of the box answer for your question is YES, you can achieve all of these through Graph API.. if you want your own customization for everything like sorting and all... Design your own branded page with full of customization and use Graph API to manage user data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could customize the Azure AD B2C UI. And it is possible to render from yor own HTML. But you cannot use JS in that HTML though.

The HTML should be uploaded in a blob and their url should be referred in the Azure AD B2C policies

Comment: Yeah. We did that. We needed more control over our properties page. We had several dependencies and a very large list we needed to load. We could not accomplish all of that with those limitations.